# Set previous page for browser back button

Tags: php, redirect

User is on page `1.php`. After sumbit form is redirect to `2.php`. Here if the browser back button is used, I want to redirect to page `3.php`.

How about something like:

- **1.php** [*submit form*] =>
- **3.php** [*header(location:2.php)*] =>
- **2.php**

Answer (score 1):

You don't. This is out of the web page's control and that is a good thing.

I would feel uneasy if a website could control by browser like that, redirecting me to a page I didn't go to when I press "Back". My first instinct would be to do a virus scan or something like that because I would think something was very wrong. How would your users react?

**Edit**: You edited the question with a proposed solution: "How about something like: *1.php* [submit form] => 3.php [header(location:2.php)] => 2.php"

If you do it with an HTTP header, some browsers may merge that into a single page in the history. It will work if you do it by means of a JavaScript redirect though, because then the browser won't be smart enough to merge them. You would also need to keep track of state (is the user submitting a form or just coming back?) and you would need to ensure the `Cache-Control` header is set appropriately (`no-cache`) so that the browser doesn't cache 3.php, because I imagine that page shouldn't look the same depending on whether you submit the form from 1.php or come back from 2.php.

However, if you didn't have a 3.php at all in the middle and did the same state tracking and `Cache-Control` on 1.php, you would get an equivalent result, so perhaps you don't need a 3.php at all.

Comment: `This is out of the web page's control` - not entirely true anymore. See [`window.onpopstate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onpopstate). Although it is true that what the OP wants to do is a bad idea and very difficult to implement, if possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use sessions. Keep your last page visited in a session variable and once the user presses the back button, your code should read that variable and redirect.

But don't count on history and stuff.

Also you might want to try history.js (even though I am still looking for that solution myself).